# Fetch data through jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery.i am try to create simple ajax call to fetch data, but i can't get data. please help me.

I am just sending request and if success than i print response but it not work, here is my code please check it.

```
<htrml>
<head>
<title> MyTest </title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<!--
        BODY { margin: 10px; padding: 0; font: 1em "Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 100%; }
        H1 { margin-bottom: 2px; }


    -->
</style>

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function () {

            var jQuery = window.$;
            $.ajax({
                url : "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                method : "GET",
                dataType : "text",
                context: document.body,
                cache : "false",
                success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('Success ... ' + data + " " + textStatus + " " + jqXHR);
                },
                error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('Error ... ' + textStatus);
                }
            });

        });

    });



    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Load" id="btn"  />


</body>
</html>
```

If you have any links related to jquery.ajax examples than suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Geez, keep your private keys private.

Comment: If you are using firefox..just put console.log(data); inside your success function and see whats returning

Answer (score 0):

dataType should be `"json"`, thats what the flickr service returns